# setInterval not repeating

Tags: javascript, web, intervals

I'm trying to change the background each 4 seconds but it jumps directly to the second condition and doesn't change anymore. Why is this happening?

```
var time = 1;
var func = function () {
    'use strict';

    if (time === 1) {
        document.getElementById("top-background").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
        time += 1;
    }

    if (time === 2) {
        document.getElementById("top-background").style.backgroundColor = "#aaa";
        time += 1;
    }

    if (time === 3) {
        document.getElementById("top-background").style.backgroundColor = "#d5d5d5";
        time -= 2;
    }

};

setInterval(func, 4000);
```

Comment: If you increment the value in an if clause, it immediately matches the next if clause. A simple, yet common mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `else if`

```
var func = function () {
    'use strict';

    if (time === 1) {
        document.getElementById("top-background").style.backgroundColor = "#000";
        time += 1;
    }

    else if (time === 2) {
        document.getElementById("top-background").style.backgroundColor = "#aaa";
        time += 1;
    }

    else if (time === 3) {
        document.getElementById("top-background").style.backgroundColor = "#d5d5d5";
        time -= 2;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

When time equals 1, you add 1 to time. This makes time equal 2. After that, you check if time equals 2, which it is! This makes you continue upwards until you reach the point where time equals to 3, and then you reset it to 1 again.

You need a way to check for only one condition. You could do this using if and elseifs:

```
if (time == 1) {
  // Code...
} else if (time == 2) {
  // Code...
} else {
  // Code...
  // Because it's not equal to 1 or 2, it must be 3.
}
```

Or, you can also use Javascript's Switch statements.

```
switch(time) {
  case 1:
    // Code...
      break;
  case 2:
    // Code...
    break;
  case 3:
    // Code...
    break;
  default:
    // Something went wrong and it's not 1, 2, or 3
  }
```